# Java HAL without extending a base class?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, hal-json

In a project I am currently working on, HAL support through the REST API is obtained by extending Springs `org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport`, in order that links can be added to an object.

A quick example:

```
public class MyDataRepresentation extends ResourceSupport {
    private String name;
}
```

Now in the web layer, I can add links in to the representation:

```
MyDataRepresentation myData = someService.getTheData();
myData.add(new Link(someUrl, someRel));
```

All well and good.

The problem is that I would rather re-use the domain object (MyData) directly, and not create a separate class in the web representation layer in order to accomplish this. The reason for this, is that my application in this particular case is simple enough that the domain object can be used directly, and I wish to avoid having mapping logic to translate to/from the web layer, either hand-coded or using a mapping tool. A further argument against mapping logic is that business logic often creeps into mapping logic, making the business logic even harder to follow.

So here is the domain class:

```
public class MyData {
    private String name;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not give me anywhere to attach my HAL links to.

So my question is, is there a HAL framework for Java, that lets me directly re-use domain objects in the web layer without resorting to using 'extends' and forcing my down the route of web/domain mapping logic?

Some other way of using HAL support in Spring that lets me do this? What about HAL support in Jersey, is that less obtrusive?

Comment: Why not just use the Spring HATEOAS `Resource<T>` class?

Comment: That works by wrapping the object instead of using extension. Yes, that would work, thanks.

Comment: Still interested to hear what support in Jersey looks like.